# Does this mean binary search algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, search

I have to write a small Java program to find out how long does it take for performing a search algorithm.

The algorithm reads as:

> Assume you have a search algorithm which, at each level of recursion, excludes half of the data from consideration when searching for a specific data item. Search stops only when one data item is left.

I would like to know your opinion about which search algorithm it is.

Comment: This is the binary search algorithm, yes. However, conceivably, there is more than just one algorithm that does this. I'm sure someone could contrive some fancy algorithm that finds a way to exclude half its input at every step and does not function as the typical binary search does.

Comment: The information provided in the question is not sufficient. The answer depends on how exactly a half of the data is excluded.

Comment: That's what is bothering me actually. This is what is mentioned in the paper for the task that I am working with. If the data is randomly inserted then it would be very complicated to find it just like this. So my conclusion was this must be a binary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like a binary search or half-interval search provided that your collection or data is sorted, worst and everage case in `O(log n)`

if you have to sort first, then the best algorithm will give you O(n log n), then plus O(log n) of binary search , overall it becomes `O(n log n)`

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have to find the time it takes to find certain item when the number of  increases exponentially

Answer (score 0):

If your data is sorted, then yes this is binary search algorithm. This algorithm comes under "Divide and Conquer" strategy. In this, each time algorithm goes on dividing the data and half of the data is eliminated. The basic assumption is data is sorted before applying the algorithm.

Comment: that would mean its a binary search algorithm. What is bothering me is , it is somehow possible to use "this algorithm" on random data ie data is not sorted